# How can I achieve High Availability with mirrored queues while load balancing on RabbitMQ nodes?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to work with a RabbitMQ cluster with all queues mirrored in order to achieve High Availability of my data. But I am worried about poor performance that can arise with lots of data pushed every seconds.

In that context, is it possible to do load balancing in some way ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid load balancing wouldn't help it at all.

[The official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) says:

> Messages published to the queue are replicated to all mirrors. Consumers are connected to the master regardless of which node they connect to, with mirrors dropping messages that have been acknowledged at the master. Queue mirroring therefore enhances availability, but does not distribute load across nodes (all participating nodes each do all the work).

So no matter on which node the queue is consumed it's actually *redirected* to the master which leads only to network overhead

There is also [a nice article](https://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) in which the behavior of the cluster is investigated.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look